# Use Filter.FilterCritera for coloring rows

Tags: c#, filter, devexpress, xtragrid

I'm using DevExpress buid-in [FilterEditor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2470) to create expressions for rows.

I don't want to apply this [FilterCriteria](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsFilteringFilterControl_FilterCriteriatopic) to actually filter data in grid, I want to color rows in green that match that expression, those that don't color in red.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the GridView's [StyleFormatCondition](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridStyleFormatConditiontopic) property:

*Style conditions allow you to create rules for changing the appearance of cells according to their contents.*